# neo4j and Groovy

Tags: groovy, neo4j

I am trying to use a script from https://gist.github.com/jexp/0617412dcdd644fd520b. There is no authors.csv file, so I created my own test file that has 3 columns: author, title and date. Then I tried to run the groovy script and got the following error

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: author
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: author
        at com.xlson.groovycsv.PropertyMapper.propertyMissing(PropertyMapper.groovy:52)
        at test.run(test.groovy:55)
```

I don't know Java and I am wondering if someone can point what happened here.

[I was running the first script that uses only 1 input file]

Added explanation. My CSV file looks like this

```
author    title    date
Auth1     Title1   date1
...       ...      ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add a header line to your CSV:

```
author,date,title
```

(Assuming that's the order in your CSV)

Comment: Edited question so that you can see the format of my file.

Comment: Have you tried using commas to separate your columns? Or passing your custom separator when you parse (as in the docs) http://xlson.com/groovycsv/

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with groovyCSV 7 years later...

The answer comes probably too late for you, but maybe it will help someone else.
In my case I was able to call every other column without any problem, but calling the first one always returned a `MissingPropertyException` exception.

Problem was that I created my csv file with Excel and this stupid software adds a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (byte order mark) at the beginning of the csv files, which prevented groovyCSV from reading correctly the header value of the first column.

Cleaning the csv file with a `dos2unix` command fixed the problem.